# redirect_to is undefined

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use a `redirect_to` in my controller and I'm getting an error complaining that redirect_to is not defined (please see logs below)

> => Booting Puma
>   => Rails 5.2.1 application starting in development
>   => Run `rails server -h` for more startup options Puma starting in   single mode...
>   * Version 3.12.0 (ruby 2.5.1-p57), codename: Llamas in Pajamas
>   * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
>   * Environment: development
>   * Listening on tcp://0.0.0.0:3000
>    Use Ctrl-C to stop Started GET  "/checkout" for 127.0.0.1 at 2018-11-22 13:18:56 -0800    (0.1ms)
>   SELECT "schema_migrations"."version" FROM "schema_migrations" ORDER BY
>   "schema_migrations"."version" ASC   ↳
>   /var/lib/gems/2.5.0/gems/activerecord-5.2.1/lib/active_record/log_subscriber.rb:98
>   ActionController::RoutingError (undefined method `redirect_to' for
>   ChargesController:Class): 
>   app/controllers/charges_controller.rb:39:in
>   `<class:ChargesController>' app/controllers/charges_controller.rb:3:in
>   `<main>'

My code is below. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. How do I go about debugging this? Any help would be appreciated.

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
  def create
    redirect_to(:controller => 'home_controller', :action => "index")
  end
```

In my rails `routes.rb` I have

```
  get "/charge",    to: "charges#create"
```

Comment: Can you paste the full error?

Comment: And does `ApplicationController` inherit from `ActionController::Base` in your codebase?

Comment: Yes, it does inherit from Acitvation:Controller::Base

Comment: In the future full error should also include the stacktrace. Can you add that too please? :)

Comment: The full error is now in the original Ticket. Thanks for the edits, I haven't posted too many questions in the past, so I apologize if this is not up to par with other posts

Comment: All good @Houman we all started that way. Happy to help! Generally speaking the more relevant information the better!

Comment: I have the feeling we are still missing some context. Since the line _"undefined method \`redirect_to' for ChargesController:Class"_ suggests that you're trying to call `redirect_to` in class context (eg. in a class method or class initialisation). The stack also points to the _ChargesController_ line 3, but only after pointing to line 39. By default controller classes don't have access to these methods, only instances of controllers can access `redirect_to`.